# Bash: run script starting from a specific line

Tags: bash

I there a way to run a bash script starting from a specific line?

Assume my script looks like that:

```
0 #!/bin/bash
1 ...
2 clone a repository
3 ...
4 command that crashed
```

I go and fix line 4 and I want to rerun the script without running the code from lines 1,2,3 but starting directly from line 4.

I quick search for the title of this question didn't give me an answer. If there is a way to do that with bash it would be useful.

Thank you for the answers. Another solution if you also want to keep some lines in the beginning is:

```
 # assuming you want to run your script except from line 4 to 7
 sed '4,7s/^/#/g' -i script.sh; ./sript.sh #this replaces the beginning of the line ^ with # from lines 4 to 7
 # to undo the comments
 sed '4,7s/^#//g' -i script.sh; ./sript.sh
```

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to do that beyond the obvious ones of commenting out or copying and pasting.

Comment: thank you, but I was looking for a faster solution on long run.

Comment: Which is why I didn't post it as an answer. Though I don't expect that you'll get a better one. Well... I suppose you might be able use something like `sed -ne '##,$p' "$script" | bash -s` if you really want to ignore *everything* above a given line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
 bash <(sed -n '5,$p' script.sh)
```

Comment: I just edit my question as I also wanted to have the option to keep some lines in the beginning uncommented. Maybe there was still a better way to do that (than my suggestions) ...such that you don't need to actually edit the script.

Comment: An alternative would be `tail -n +5 script.sh | bash`. However, with either of these, if you get your line numbers mixed up and, for example, tell it to start running in the middle of a loop, things are gonna break...

Comment: That's so ugly it's beautiful!

Comment: @twalberg to counter the line number mixup, I tried `cat -n script.sh` where `-n` gives the line numbers. After that I knew from which line to select using `tail`

Answer (score 0):

A different approach that worked in my case:

```
if [[ $1 != skip ]]
then
"do the first part of program"
./$0 skip
else
"do rest of program"
fi
```

Here im calling the script recursivly but adding the argument "skip" so that
it skips the first part of the program.